# How can I convert json format sentence to another one by using C# regex for elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, razor

I have very strange json problem . I need to convert UrlQueryString to another standard for elasticsearch . when you look at below you will see that 2 json . I want to change :
**FROM**  `"UrlQueryString": "checkinDate: 2020-07-01,checkoutDate: 2020-07-05,room: Y,Y,Y",` 
 **TO** 
 `"UrlQueryString": {"checkinDate":"2020-07-01","checkoutDate":"2020-07-05","room": "Y,Y,Y"}`

How can I do that? I think that I need regex or another options. also I tried many times for this by using replacing and removing.

I have below string json:

```
{
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "CorrelationId": "44160536-a1e9-4a5b-a19d-9e2323ebfa7a",
  "UrlMethod": "GET",
  "Data": "",
  "UrlQueryString": "checkinDate: 2020-07-01,checkoutDate: 2020-07-05,room: Y,Y,Y",
  "UrlPath": /xxxx",
  "LogSource": "source1",
  "LogDate": "2019-12-28T07:39:24.2434156Z",
  "Environment": "xxxx"
}
```

My desired result:

```
{
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "CorrelationId": "44160536-a1e9-4a5b-a19d-9e2323ebfa7a",
  "UrlMethod": "GET",
  "Data": "",
  "UrlQueryString": {"checkinDate":"2020-07-01","checkoutDate":"2020-07-05","room": "Y,Y,Y"},
  "UrlPath": "/xxxx",
  "LogSource": "source1",
  "LogDate": "2019-12-28T07:39:24.2434156Z",
  "Environment": "xxxx"
}
```

important NOTE: Don't forget something. UrlQueryString is not static. It's exactly dynamic.
at the end of the day;

```
"UrlQueryString": {"Parameter2": "bird"," anyvalue": "fly"}
```

or

```
"UrlQueryString": {"Parameter2": "bird"," anyvalue": "fly","Parameter3": "bird"," anyvalue2": "fly"}
```

```
{
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "CorrelationId": "44160536-a1e9-4a5b-a19d-9e2323ebfa7a",
  "UrlMethod": "GET",
  "Data": "",
  "UrlQueryString": {"Parameter1": "Kuş"," test1": "1577518755769"},
  "UrlPath": "/Json/AutoCompleteHotelCallBack",
  "LogSource": "xxxrwr",
  "LogDate": "2019-12-28T07:39:24.2434156Z",
  "Environment": "xx-1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`UrlQueryString` value is not a valid json or something that can be converted to json with standard processes**

**Issues:**

1. Its a string without curly braces `{}`.
2. Its a string with key and value representation without quotes {"key", "value"}
3. You can try doing Splits on `,` and `:` but that would not work as you have `,` in your values with possibility of an object (JArray or JObject) as a value. `{"key": "val,ue"}` or `{"key": { "key2": "value" } }`

**ONLY IFF** you can be sure that you will have only Keys and string literals for value in that string, you can use the following method to convert that string to a json. `{"key": "value", "key2": "val,ue2"}`

1. Convert `string` to an `array` containing keys and values in order.
2. Convert array to `Dictionary<string,string>` so `JsonConvert` can convert to object.

```
    public static object ConvertStringToJson (string convertThisToJson)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(convertThisToJson))
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{}"));

        string[] splitStr = convertThisToJson.Split(':');
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string key, value;

        // First element will always be Key
        key = splitStr[0];

        // Everything in the middle will be Value/NextKey pair (not key/Value)
        for (int i = 1; i < splitStr.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            // You suggested your value could have commas ... thus LastIndexOf
            int indexSplit = splitStr[i].LastIndexOf(",");

            value = splitStr[i].Substring(0, indexSplit);
            dict.Add(key, value.Trim());

            key = splitStr[i].Substring(indexSplit + 1);
        }

        // Last element in its entirety will be value.
        value = splitStr[splitStr.Length - 1];
        dict.Add(key, value.Trim());

        // You can choose to do either of these.
        //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict); // Do change the return type if you decide to go with this.
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
    }
```

and use it like this

```
    string str = "checkinDate: 2020-07-01,checkoutDate: 2020-07-05,room: Y,Y,Y";
    object jsonObj = ConvertStringToJson(str);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.ToString()); // Print Json Object
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj)); // Print String
```

**Output**

```
// Json Object.
{
  "checkinDate": "2020-07-01",
  "checkoutDate": "2020-07-05",
  "room": "Y,Y,Y"
}

// String
{"checkinDate":"2020-07-01","checkoutDate":"2020-07-05","room":"Y,Y,Y"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking too complicated.
You could easily get away with just a normal string replacement. And there would be no risk either, unless one of the values could somehow get a value that's the same as a key. Doesn't seem possible though.

Maybe not the most professional solution, but I doubt that's what you're after. Or if you are, my apologies.

So just a few string replacements on that particular row and it's good to be parsed as a json.
Examples:

```
.Replace("\"checkinDate: ", "{\"checkinDate:\"")
.Replace(",checkoutDate: ", "\",\"checkoutDate\":\"")
```

Comment: Hi; I added my question for some detail because you misunderstand something. UrlQueryString is dynamic not static.